# C# Priority List

Tags: c#, data-structures

I'm having trouble finding the right C# data structure.  I'm looking for a PriorityList.  It needs to have the following:

- Only one item a given priority
- Must remain sorted at all times
- Ability to add an item to the end of the list -- prorityList.Add(item)
- Ability to insert an item at a given priority -- priorityList.Add(3, item)
- Ability to access any element using the priority -- priorityList[3]
- Ability to remove an item at a given priority -- priorityList.RemoveAt(3)
- When an item is added or removed, the rest of the list must shift up or down appropriately -- for example, if the third item is removed, the fourth item becomes the third item, the fifth item becomes the fourth item, etc.

C#'s SortedList looked promising, but it can't handle inserting at a priority that already exists or removing an element at a given priority (having the list shift appropriately in both cases).

Comment: Sounds like a LinkedList http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/he2s3bh7.aspx

Comment: If you want to sort it by priority then Traverse List will be helpful.

Comment: VS Magazine has a functional/testable implementation that you may wish to review http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2012/11/01/priority-queues-with-c.aspx

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you just use a standard `List<T>` that should give you everything you have asked for if you use `priority == index.`

Comment: Thanks, can't believe I didn't figure that out myself!

Answer (score 0):

How about using `SortedDictionary<TKey, TValue>` where the key is priority? It doesn't quite fit all of your requirements, and its not clear if you want priority to be unique or not. If you doen't want priority to be unique, `LinkedList<T>` is probably your best bet.